# How to Authorize and sign in at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, security, azure-ad-b2c

To use my app, a user must go through the sign in process to be granted access to the various parts of the app. So regardless of the entrance to the app (whether they start at /home, or /somethingElse), I'd like the user to be authorized and given their permissions.
Their permissions come from the SignUpSignIn() function in the Account controller.

When a user tries to access /somethingElse, I have an [Authorize] attribute that sends them to the Azure B2C sign in. But after being "Authorized" the SignUpSignIn() function is never hit and their permissions aren't assigned to their session. So whatever location they end up at, doesn't work properly (
and likely errors).
How can I get a user to run through the SignUpSignIn() after being authorized?

This is how I'm Authorizing

```cs
namespace TaskWebApp.Controllers
{
[Authorize]  //<---
    public class SomethingElseController : Controller
    {
        // GET: SomethingElse
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how a user gets their permissions.

```cs
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {
     public async Task SignUpSignIn()
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            { ///}
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            { //apply permissions to user's session }
        }
     }
```

I expect a user to go to /somethingelse, and be redirected to the Azure B2C SignIn page. Once they click "sign in" to run SignUpSignIn() from the Account controller and have their permissions assigned to their session.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that this isn't a good method of reapplying the permissions via session. 
Instead I have created something that looks like this:

```cs
namespace TaskWebApp.Controllers
{
[Authorize] 
    public class SomethingElseController : Controller
    {
       public async Task<ActionResult> Index(){
           if(Session["foo"] == null){ //there is no session data
               await SignUpSignIn("/somethingelse") //This goes to the account controller and applies permissions on the session
           }
           else 
           {
               return View();
           }
        }
       private async Task SignUpSignIn(string redirectLink = "")
        {
            var controller = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<AccountController>();
            controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(Request.RequestContext, controller);
            await controller.SignUpSignIn(redirectLink);
        }
    }
}
```